# Bessel derivatives

Tags: series-expansion, special-functions

I tried to expand `BesselJ[k,x]` function into a Taylor series with `Series` command. Here both `k` and `x` are some functions of the expansion variable $\lambda$, so in the expansion, derivatives with respect to both `k` and `x` occur.

The problem is, whenever there is a term that is the derivative of both variables, *Mathematica* leaves it as (e.g.) `Derivative[2, 1][BesselJ][0., 2.40483]` and doesn't give a numerical value in the end.

First I thought it is because assigned values aren't exact -- since the above `2.40483` is the value of `BesselJZero[0, 1]`. However, it also doesn't give numerical or analytical result for the following easier calculation:

```
D[BesselJ[k, x], {k, 1}, {x, 1}] /. {k -> 1, x -> 1} // N
(* -> Derivative[1, 1][BesselJ][1., 1.] *)
```

But, when the order of the differentiation changes, it gives numerical results:

```
D[BesselJ[k, x], {x, 1}, {k, 1}] /. {k -> 0, x -> 1} // N
(* -> 1.22713 *)
```

It works with `x -> BesselJZero[0, 1]` as well.

First question: why is this the case?

Second (if it is possible): how can I handle it with `Series` command?

Comment: I edited your question because the formatting was a bit off. Please take care not to use the backtick (`\``) as an apostrophe (`'`)!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Use `FunctionExpand`.

Longer answer:
This indeed a bit odd at first glance. However, it seems to be more a property of the Bessel functions than of `D`. In any case, using `FunctionExpand` solves the problem:

```
D[BesselJ[k, x], k, x] /. {k -> 1, x -> 1} // N
FunctionExpand[%]
```

yields

```
0.160512
```

Now, that seems to work in a series as well:

```
Normal@Series[BesselJ[ Sin[x], Cos[x]], {x, 0, 3}] // N
```

gives

```
 0.7651976865579666 + 0.13863371520404605*x - 0.6542004860899648*x^2 + 
 0.16666666666666666*x^3*(2.5114247538954846 - 3.*Derivative[1, 1][BesselJ][0., 1.])
```

Applying `FunctionExpand` on it, resolves the remaining symbolic derivatives

```
FunctionExpand[%]
0.7651976865579666 + 0.13863371520404605*x - 0.6542004860899648*x^2 -  0.19499232275587164*x^3
```

Comment: Actually I forgot to say I use `FullSimplify`which does the same with `FunctionExpand` as far as I know and now I realized that the problem starts when $2^{nd}$ derivative with respect to `k` is taken. Mathematica can't find a numerical results. It is fine if the order of the derivative with respect to `k` is only one.

Comment: Well, If I try 

D[BesselJ[k, x], k, x] /. {k -> 2, x -> 1} // N
FunctionExpand[%]

I get -0.212053 as an answer, so I don't quite understand your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can get numerical series expansions by using the `NumericalCalculus` package, which offers the function `NSeries`. I'll illustrate this with some simple made-up functions on which the `BesselJ` arguments depend, as you describe. Using `ϵ` as the small parameter, I define the fifth-order series expansion as `f[ϵ_]` and compare it to the exact function.

To make the numerics work reliably, I have to specify a radius on which the function is sampled. I choose this small enough to exclude the potentially troublesome points where the Bessel arguments are zero.

```
<< NumericalCalculus`

f[ϵ_] = 
 Chop@Normal[
   NSeries[BesselJ[1 + ϵ^2, 
     Sin[Pi/4 + ϵ]], {ϵ, 0, 5}, Radius -> .5]]

(*
==> 0.331912 + 0.289531 ϵ - 0.681305 ϵ^2 - 
 0.0643912 ϵ^3 + 0.546373 ϵ^4 - 0.636954 ϵ^5
*)

Plot[{f[ϵ], 
  BesselJ[1 + ϵ^2, Sin[Pi/4 + ϵ]]}, {ϵ, 
  -.5, .5}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

[image: comparison]

This shows that the expansion worked as it should.